# how to assign an Action to the subscription method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to use the Just operator as shown in the code below. As shown in the code, I am trying to create an Action and then pass it to the subscription method
but I receive error on the following liine of code:

```
        getJustOperator().subscribe(onNextAction);
        //Error message: cant resolve method
```

please let me know how to create an Action correctly.
I posted also the rx lib I am using

**imports**:

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Action;
```

**Rx lib**:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

**code**:

```
Action onNextAction = new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Log.i(TAG, "Run: Just Operator");
        }
    };
    getJustOperator().subscribe(onNextAction);
}

private Observable<String> getJustOperator() {
    return Observable.just("Just Operator");
}
```

Comment: To consume each next item use `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer`. `Action` is for the `onComplete` event. Have a look at the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html)

Comment: can you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the subscribe-overload with onNext please review this example:

```
Observable.just("Wurst")
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                    Log.i("MYTAG", "Run: Just Operator");
                }
            });
```

You must pass an Consumer. There are other overloads for onComplete and onError. Just have a look at the method-signature in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe--)